# Waiting for a webservice method result to the the other

Tags: web-services, silverlight-4.0

I'm writing a silverlight 4 application and calling 2 methods in a row, as example

```
getCarsCompleted()
getCarsAsync()

getJouneyCompleted()
getJourneyAsync()
```

i bind the results to the respective data grid

I have a web service with 2 functions:

`getCars()` which give me a list of cars with their id and modelname
`getJourney(time)` which give me all the journeys in specified time

if the journeys only have the id of a participating car.

therefore i have to know the model names by getCars().

Happens that not always i have the car model names of journeys populated in the data grid.

How can i make it to grant the results of getCars() before getJourneys();

---

I've already used manualresetevent. But in this case I'm calling at the MainPage and if i do a WaitOne() i lock it.

Sorry if I'm not explaining my self right. I have to make sure if the getAsync() for cars happens first than the Journeys.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using AutoResetEvent class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksb7zs2x(v=vs.95).aspx